# Autenticación con Firebase no funciona en dispositivo físico

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-auth

Estoy teniendo problemas para iniciar sesión en una app con `Firebase Auth` utilizando Gmail como método de LogIn.

El proceso solo funciona perfectamente con dispositivos emulados virtuales cuando la app esta en modo de depuracion.

No funciona si:

-El cel es físico.

-El cel es virtual pero esta en modo release.

Si lo ejecuto por pasos lo que sucede con el dispositivo físico es que ejecuta bien el `Paso #1`, solicita que el usuario elija una cuenta de Gmail para iniciar sesión (hasta aquí todo bien), pero al seleccionar una cuenta se queda como si nada pasara (cuando debería irse al `Paso #2`).

No entiendo que sucede, si algo estuviera mal arrojaría algún error o no funcionaria nunca, cierto?

(Cabe mencionar que de momento en este proyecto utilizo una cuenta de Firebase "gratuita").

Después de seleccionar el correo en esta vista (imagen adjunta) se finaliza el intent y simplemente queda el Layout del Login sin que nada mas ocurra.

[image: Login]

**Código:**

```
if (firebaseAuth.CurrentUser == null)
                {
                    var intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
                    StartActivityForResult(intent, 1); 
                
                    //Envio de Activity. Paso #1
                }
```

--------------------------------------------*

```
//Recepcion de resultado de Activity. Paso #2

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
            {
                try
                {
                    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    
                    if (requestCode == 1)
                    {
                        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.GetSignInResultFromIntent(data);
                        if (result.IsSuccess) //Inicio sesion // OK
                        {
                            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.SignInAccount;
                            LoginWithFirebase(account);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.MakeText(this, "Inicio de sesion fallido. Servicio no inicia.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception Ex)
                {
                    string LineErrorNumber = Ex.StackTrace.Substring(Ex.StackTrace.Length - 7, 7) + Ex.Message;
                }
```

--------------------------------------------*

Comment: Pero, ¿qué hace, muestra el mensaje del  `else` en el `Toast`? Si no muestra nada, intenta mostrar el mensaje del `catch`  para obtener detalles del error.

Comment: Ese es el problema. No muestra ningún error, no quiebra, no entra en el Else. NADA. Simplemente se congela. Si lo pruebo en diferentes virtuales ahi continua el flujo sin problemas.

Comment: Si puedes conecta el dispositivo por USB e intenta así, cuando ocurren errores los muestra en el Log cat.

Comment: Buena idea pero aun nada. El Log no muestra nada (literalmente). Al darle click al Btn de Iniciar sesion me pide seleccionar el correo, selecciono el correo pero el Log no muestra nada después de cargar el Main, y de igual forma despues de seleccionar el correo la app se queda sin hacer nada.

Comment: No puede ser. Ten en cuenta que en la parte de Log (si usas Android Studio) hay varias pestañas y varios niveles de log. Hay uno que es Verbose, que muestra absolutamente todo lo que ocurre en el dispositivo cuando lo tienes conectado, muestra por decir algo, hasta la intesidad de la señal Wifi, y muestra todas las pantallas que se cargan, los recursos que se consumen, etc. Ahí debe aparecer el error. **Hay que aprender a depurar**, a bucear en los programas de Log, te ahorrarás incluso días, porque en unos pocos minutos esos Logs te ayudarán a encontrar exactamente el problema.

Comment: Hay un nivel de depuración donde se ve [una ventana parecida a la que muestra la documentación de Android](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug?hl=es#systemLogView). Ahí aparece todo, todo lo que va ocurriendo en el dispositivo. En la parte superior de esa ventana hay también otros tipos de filtros que debes aprender a usar. Está claro que para que funcione debes tener habilitado el modo desarrollador en el dispositivo y haber otorgado los permisos que fueren necesarios. Lo repito de nuevo: dedícale todo el tiempo que tengas que dedicarle a aprender a depurar, no es tiempo perdido.